# Correct way to dismiss keyboard from a TextView in Nativescript

Tags: textview, uitextview, nativescript

I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView id="textFieldBody" hint="Some hint" text="{{  }}" editable="true" class="TextField" returnKeyType="done" />
```

I'm trying to correctly implement it so that:

- when the user presses "Done", the keyboard disappears
- when the user touches outside (blur) of the TextView, the keyboard
  disappears
- maybe when focus on the TextView, scroll up so that the rest of the
  view doesn't disappear behind the keyboard? (not sure yet about this
  one)

It's unclear to me how to achieve that. What kind of backend code do I need to implement?

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that works for both iOS and Android.

Comment: for hiding the keyboard you could use `dismissSoftInput` method -https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_editable_text_base_.editabletextbase.html#dismisssoftinput .

Comment: @NikolayTsonev thanks! I've seen that but I'm not sure how to implement it? I've added it like that: page.getViewById("textFieldBody").dismissSoftInput(); to my onLoaded function but it doesn't work. Pressing the done key returns to a new line.

Comment: The blur effect has been resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39949110

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**When the user press done, keyboard disappears**

For this one, you can put a listener to the textview so that it will get triggered when user press the `done` button. As I had a look at [NativeScript API](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html), this listener is only applied for TextField, but you can give TextView a try:

In XML:

```
<TextField returnPress="doneTap"/>
```

In .js file:

```
function doneTap(args) {
    var myTextField = args.object;
    myTextField.dismissSoftInput();
}
exports.doneTap = doneTap
```

**When the user touches outside (blur) of the TextView, the keyboard disappears**

For this one, you will put a listener to the parent view of the TextField. When you tap outside, it will invoke the function to hide the keyboard. The good thing is that this listener will be overrided by TextField tap. So when you tap on the TextField, the keyboard still shows up. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949110/hide-android-keyboard-in-nativescript-on-input-field-blur/39952858#39952858)

**When focus on the TextView, scroll up so that the rest of the view doesn't disappear behind the keyboard?**

Using this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager) to prevent keyboard from covering the textfield

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried returnPress earlier today but it doesn't work with TextView.

Comment: Ok so, for the third part of my question, see this issue on Github: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/166 and this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager :)

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot that I'm also using that plugin but it's only for iOS.

Comment: In the second question, for the ios, I think that it will be `myTextField.ios.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: I will update the third question so others will know

Comment: Thanks! It is, yes. I edited my comment as I found the solution just a few minutes after :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the last plugin solution